# How to style ion-input labels on ionic 7?

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic7

I'm migrating an app to ionic 7 which encourage stop using <ion-label> for ion-input among others. In all the guides I am seeing I see how you only have to put the text in the slot of ion-input and set the labelPlacement property but in my case I don't have text but I do have a class applied to that <ion-label> and I do not have how to apply it the new way.

This is the current code:

```
<ion-label class="eva-form-label" position="stacked"></ion-label>
      <ion-input
        class="form__select"
        formControlName="item"
        placeholder="{{ getSelectPlaceholder() | translate }} *"
        (click)="openModal()"
      ></ion-input>
```

I tried to so something like this:

```
<ion-input
        class="form__select eva-form-label"
        labelPlacement="stacked"
        formControlName="item"
        placeholder="{{ getSelectPlaceholder() | translate }} *"
        (click)="openModal()"
      ></ion-input>
```

Creating this class in my scss file:

```
&.eva-form-label {
      font-size: 16px;
      margin-bottom: 7px;
      opacity: 1 !important;
      transform: none;
      --webkit-transform: none;
  }
```

But it just does not apply the class, any ideas?

Comment: If you don't have text to put into the label, why do you need to style it? The only thing I saw that caught my eyes was the `margin-bottom: 7px;`. Are you using the blank label to create white spaces between the inputs?

Comment: Thanks for answer, I think that is the case but I'm not really sure I didn't do that code I'm just working on it

Comment: You need to check the history to find out who did this. Then talk to them to make sure it's the case. Once the person confirms that this was to add the whitespace, then you use  CSS `Grid` with `gap` to introduce the whitespaces.